# Even $k$ such that $x^k \equiv -1 \mod k+1$ has solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there an even positive integer $k$ such that the equation $x^k \equiv -1 \mod (k+1)$ has solutions?
Of course, for odd $k$, $x=-1$ is a solution. This is relevant to OEIS sequence [A330279](https://oeis.org/A330279).

If my Maple program is correct, there are no such $k < 10000$.  Also all prime factors of $k+1$ must be $\equiv 1 \mod 4$, so $k$ must be divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such $k$.

Let $k = 2^nk_1$, $k_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. It is a well known fact that all odd prime divisors of $y^{2^n} + 1$ are of the form $2^{n+1}m + 1$. Hence, if $k + 1 \mid x^k + 1$, then all prime divisors of $k + 1$ are of the form $2^{n+1}m + 1$. Hence, $k + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{n + 1}}$, which is impossible, because $k$ is not divisible by $2^{n + 1}$.